# How to implement custom components in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, components

I've created a simple test program in React which displays a piece of text.

```
import React from 'react';
import componentClass from './components/componentClass';

export default function App () {

    return (
      <h1>example</h1>
    )
  }
```

What I'm trying to do now is take this example text and make it its own separate component. I've created a class component named `componentClass` where the example text is displayed.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class componentClass extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <h1>example</h1>
    )
  }
}
```

I'm then rendering this component in App.js.

```
import React from 'react';
import componentClass from './components/componentClass';

export default function App () {

  return (
    <componentClass />
  )
}
```

The problem is that nothing is showing up so I'm confused as to why the component isn't being displayed. Below is my index.js file.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
reportWebVitals();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using PascalCase when naming React components

[working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r1hs923y/)

```
class ComponentClass extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <h1>Component class</h1>
    )
  }
}

function App () {
  return (
    <ComponentClass />
  )
}
  
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

Answer (score 1):

In React, ALl components should have the first letter capitalized which means you need to edit each time you mentioned `componentClass` and turn it into `ComponentClass`

Comment: I see, I'm so used to camel case that I never thought to use pascal case

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your return in a react fragment like so:

```
 return (
   <>
    <ComponentClass />
   </>
  )
```

Comment: No, it still doesn't display.